# serving static files in Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-staticfiles

I'm quite new to Django and I have a problem that I cannot solve for a long time already. Would appreciate any hint!

The question is why does it find static files for base.html and cannot find it for login.html(they are even in the same directory)? Everything works fine, django manages to find template "index.html", which extends "base.html" and shows it with a nice bootstrap example.   However, when I click login, and go to accounts/login (I use django-allauth), I get the error:

```
"GET /accounts/login/static/twitter_bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 7044
"GET /accounts/login/static/twitter_bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 404 7038
```

Thus, it doesn't load bootstrap and js.. I tried so many workarounds, debug shows that it points to correct path.. The processes of login/logout/etc. work fine.

What I want to do is to define in base.html that I want to use bootstrap files, and then simply extend this behavior to other templates as well. Can someone help, please?

My static files live in the project folder under static name.

```
-Project Dir
  -static
     -static
         -twitter_bootstrap
     -static-only
     -media
     -templates
         -account
             -base.html
             -login.html
         -signups(app name)
             -index.html
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates"),
```

)

Base.html:

```
{% load url from future %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% block headbootstrap %}
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Basic css -->
<link href="static/twitter_bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
<title>{% block head_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
{% block extra_head %}
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block header %}
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <!-- Mobile Nav Button -->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <!-- END Mobile Nav Button -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HumanPulse</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navigation Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <!—Show Home and News -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
            </ul>
          {%else%}
    <!—Show Dashboard and Data -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#yourdata">Data</a></li>
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        <!-- END Navigation Links -->
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" href="/accounts/logout/" >Logout</a>
                {% if request.user.first_name or request.user.last_name %}
                    {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ request.user.username }}
                {% endif %}
            {% if request.user.profile.account_verified %} (verified) {% else %} (unverified) {% endif %}

            {% else %}
                <a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" href="/accounts/login/" >Login</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if redirect_field_value %}
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
            {% endif %}
          </form>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
 <div class="container">

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
<div class="container">
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}


</div> <!-- /container -->

{% endblock %}
{% block extra_body %}
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
<footer>
    <p>&copy; Blog 2013</p>
    </footer>
{% endblock %}
<script src="static/twitter_bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'account/base.html' %}

{% block head_title %}ProjectName{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Voila!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

login.html

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign In" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<a href="/accounts/facebook/login/"><div class="fb"></div></a>
{% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}
<div class="inset">
    <div class="header">Or sign in directly</div>
    <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <input id="id_login" class="login-input" maxlength="30" name="login" placeholder="Username" type="text" />{{ form.login.errors }}<br>
        <input id="id_password"  class="login-input" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />{{ form.password.errors }}<br>
        <div class="remember-forgot-section">
            <input id="id_remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="id_remember">Remember Me</label>
            <a class="forgot" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
        </div>
      {% if redirect_field_value %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
      {% endif %}

      <button class="btn" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
    </form>

    <div class="footnote">
        Don't have an account? Login with Facebook above or <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: I solved it by: <link href="{% static "twitter_bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> in the base.html :)

Comment: Just for extra info, you forgot to add an initial forward slash therefore your url paths were relative. Instead of looking for your files in /static your browser was pointing to accounts/login/static